# Правильно ли построена фраза?

Tags: правила

**Тогда пусть пьет этот сок и лимонад, которые его руководство заставляет закупать местные магазины.**

Смущает: "которые его руководство..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё нормально.Его руководство заставляет местные магазины закупать сок и лимонад, вот и пусть их пьёт.Всё понятно.Союзное слово стоит сразу после определяемых слов в главном предложении.

Answer (score 0):

Тогда пусть пьет этот сок и лимонад, которые его руководство заставляет закупать местные магазины.

1) Для начала  в  этом предложении  я бы  заменила сочетание **"его руководство" с неясной семантикой**: он руководит этими людьми или они им руководят.

**Вариант 1:** Тогда пусть пьет этот сок и лимонад, которые **его чиновники** заставляют закупать местные магазины.

Конечно, и эту фразу не каждый человек  сразу поймет ввиду инверсии  двух прямых объектов (которые и магазины), отнесенных к разным глаголам  (что будем закупать: магазины или лимонад?).

Вариант 2 (совсем понятный): **Тогда пусть пьет этот сок и лимонад, которые магазины закупают по принуждению его чиновников.**

Comment: (1) Согласен с тем, что вариант 2 понятней. (2) Не думаю, что тут есть неясная семантика. Руководство - это руководители (в данном контексте). Его руководство - его руководители. Вполне однозначно. Как еще можно эту фразу понимать? Его руководящая деятельность заставляет закупать сок? Настолько коряво, что вряд ли кому придет в голову такая трактовка.

Comment: А вот мне неясно, кто кого заставляет: он  - своих подчиненных чиновников или его  - стоящие над ним начальники.  Не понимаю, что в этой фразе вообще можно найти "нормального", слишком высокая оценка для такого письма.